# How to enable SSL on Nginx reverse proxy on cPanel?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, nginx

I am running cPanel/WHM 11.30 on CentOS 5.6, Apache 2.2 and Nginx Admin 2.5 (as reverse proxy). The Nginx bit is reasonably new to me so the following question may be somewhat noob.

I want to secure (SSL) a domain and not sure if these steps are the right aproach, given my specific setup (Nginx, Apache, cPanel). I found this but would prefer to validate before messing up my server:

http://kbeezie.com/view/free-ssl-with-nginx/3/

Would this work for the environment I described or otherwise, can anyone share some pointers?

Comment: Hm, I'd never heard of this package, cool. Also, the listed [installation instructions](http://nginxcp.com/installation-instruction/) (see *admin* comments) say it doesn't support `SSL`. The date is Dec 2010, so I don't know if that's correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the [installation instructions](http://nginxcp.com/installation-instruction/), there is a *site-admin* comment, dated Dec 2010:

> SSL is not supported currently by
>   Nginx Admin

There is nothing else about SSL on the site, so I'd say no, it's still not supported.